# Save WinForm to PDF & print multipage WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pdf

How can I save multipage WinForm to PDF & how can I print it?

thanks, 
Ofir

Answer (score 1):

A good framework is [pdfSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/).

You can capture the form (there are few ways of doing it, [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/imagecapture.aspx) is one sample).
Than write the image stream a pdf object (you can find many samples for this in the pdfSharp web site).

Answer (score 1):

You can use paint method to capture the entire client area of your Form and then use the Print method to print them.

```
 Graphics myGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
 Size s = this.Size;
 memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics);
 Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
 memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, 0, 0, s);
```

then use PrintDocument class to print it.