# Create a pdf of scrollable winform

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

I had a situation like creating a pdf file from the winform, which have to make entire winform as a pdf,  most of the searching in the google resulted in capturing the screen and making the pdf of that, but the problem is that it will not be useful if the form is lengthy, and it have scroll bars.

I referred to these links which are not much useful

[convert windows form to pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813341/convert-windows-form-to-pdf-file|)

[Save WinForm to PDF & print multipage WinForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101401/save-winform-to-pdf-print-multipage-winform)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Certainly you can insert a multi-line textbox into PDF (with I think no more than approx 65,000 chars). There are many software solutions to create PDF Forms and you can set the text of that form field to your scrollable form.

Comment: I doesn't mean that lengthy form is due to the multiline textbox it is because of the more content controls @KevinBrown

Comment: Maybe: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2ad34554-e989-4ffa-8e1f-ccea1f00c99d/how-to-print-scrollable-textbox

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var form = new Form1();
    var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(form.Width,form.Height);
    form.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, form.Bounds);
    bitmap.Save("file.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    bitmap.Dispose();
```

Comment: here panel in the sense our main panel?

Comment: i've modified the answer. Form is the ancestor of Control. You can Draw the hole form to Bitmap.

Comment: no it is not working as my form is having the scrollbar as mentioned in the question it is truncating some part of the above part of the form... and making an image

Comment: try capture the root control of the form

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35890/discussion-between-raghurocks-and-vasiliy)